# White background on CSS Like Box

Tags: css, background, facebook-likebox

The current dark/light styles for the FB Like Box dont work on a transparent/semi transparent page layout.  The like box ends up inheriting the attributes of the page, becoming transparent.

I tried to reset the facebook like box css by creating a fb.css file with the necessary corrections, and adding css="fb.css" into the code as indicated has worked on this forum.  However it does not seem to work.

Is there a way to get the FB Like Box to have a simple white background when used on a transparent page?  I was able to accomplish this in firebug by editing the attribute          .connect_widget {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

The website in question is http://www.laudanumonline.com, like box is in the lower right corner.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `!important` to override the styles set by Facebook:

```
.connect_widget {background-color: #fff !important;}
```

Comment: I tried this. I apologize for not posting it in my initial question.  It didnt seem to have any effect.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Firebug because it adds the style as an inline style.

One way to do this is to add the style as an inline-style with some jQuery.  Something like

`$('.connect_widget').css({'background-color':'#fff');`

You would probably need to set this to an event, though, unless the box is visible on page load.

Comment: The box is visible on page load.  Where in the code would I put something like this?  Im not horribly familiar with how jQuery works.  Is this something I'd have in the page.tpl.php file?

Answer (score 0):

You may not style the ".connect_widget" div, but you can style the iframe it's in, or even the div that the iframe is in. In my case, my like box is located in a div "#fb-platform" so I can easily do this:

```
#fb-platform iframe {background-color: #fff; }
```

or

```
#fb-platform .fb-like-box {background-color: #fff; }
```

Any of these options works fine.

The like box is still transparent, but the parent iframe/div isn't, therefore - white background.

Comment: And that's why they made it transparent. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put that connect widget in a single cell table and make the table background white?  That's what I did on www.earthakitt.com (inner pages, not the homepage) in the column on the right.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add style="background:#fff;" to element

Answer (score 0):

I use this and it works. :) Put the  code at the end of your css file.

```
span>iframe{background:#ffffff !important;}
```